# What do i use now that Anko is deprecated?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko, anko-component

How do I fix the deprecation warning in this code? Alternatively, are there any other options for doing this?

```
   runOnUiThread {

        doAsync {
             // room insert query
        }
   }
// anko Commons
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.8"
```

Comment: And what do you want to do? Run insert query in background thread and return to UI? Then you should use coroutines or RxJava.

Comment: thank u, i have plan to use coroutines & also going to remove anko lib in my project

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR**: I would honestly HIGHLY **recommend** making full use of `Kotlin`.

Since I do not know your exact purpose of `Anko`, I will answer very generally.

`Anko` was great, but now it is time to move on... Although there are several alternatives out there, `Kotlin` itself is the "Best" alternative to `Anko`

1. You could *make* all the **general helper methods** from `Anko` using `Kotlin's Extension functions`. ([read more](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions))

   Like this:

   ```
    fun MutableList<Int>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int) {
        val tmp = this[index1] // 'this' corresponds to the list
        this[index1] = this[index2]
        this[index2] = tmp
    }

    val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
    list.swap(0, 2) // 'this' inside 'swap()' will hold the value of 'list'
   ```
2. You could use the state-of-the-art async programming library called `Coroutine` which Waaaaay faster than `RxJava`. ([read more](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#your-first-coroutine))

   ```
   fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { // launch a new coroutine and continue
        delay(1000L) // non-blocking delay for 1 second (default time unit is ms)
        println("World!") // print after delay
    }
    println("Hello") // main coroutine continues while a previous one is delayed
    }
   ```
3. And much more to fulfill your needs.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

As they say on their deprecation page on [github](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/GOODBYE.md), there are more alternatives. As for commons they provide two libs, all the links are [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/GOODBYE.md#generic-utilities), keep in mind that some of these libs can be deprecated since last update of that page was 2 years ago.